# Recursive serialization causing stack overflow error in vc10/11 but not in vc9

Tags: c++, visual-c++, serialization, recursion, mfc

Recursive serialization using MFC in vc10 and vc11 causing stackl overflow error.This error does not come on vc9.

---

Hi,

I am serializing following class object.This class is linked list.

------------- MyClass.h-----------

```
class MyClass : public CObject
{
protected:
 MyClass  *m_pNext;     
 int var1;   
 enum1 var2;
 enum2 var3;
 enum3 var4;
 double[3] m_Normal;  

public:
// Serialization
    DECLARE_SERIAL_MICRO
    void Serialize(CArchive& ar);   
};
```

So here size of MyClass is very less and is less than 30-40 bytes.

---

------------- MyClass.cpp-----------

```
    IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(MyClass , CObject,  VERSIONABLE_SCHEMA | 6)

    void MyClass::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
    {   

        ar.SerializeClass(RUNTIME_CLASS(MyClass)); 
        UINT objSch = ar.GetObjectSchema();
        CObject::Serialize(ar); 

        if(ar.IsStoring())
        {
     //store all variables
     ......

     //Store Next pointer

     ar<< m_pNext;
        }
        else
        {
     //Retrive all variables
     ......

     //Deserialize Next pointer       

      ar >> m_pNext;  // This is recursive deserialization call 
         }

}
```

---

Now here if MYClass linked list size is crossing ~4000 items limit.Stack overflow error occurs.
This error comes only in vc10 and vc11.
For same code and data size , stack overflow error does not come for vc9.

vc11 analysis data:
Before De-Serialization starts: @esp = 2285040
I put breakpoint at the starts of seralization function.
For each iteration MyClass stack grows by 512 bytes.The size of myclass is not that much. I think MFC internally using stack for his own purpose while deserialization.

So approximately after 4000 items: @esp = 2283968.
At this point stack utlizaton is 2MB .So as stack totally exhausted ,crash occurs.

Our exe has stack limit of 2MB.

vc9 analysis data:
Before De-Serialization : @esp = 2282960
Then for each Myclass stack grows by 336 bytes and it comes back to original or near to original value after one or two recursive calls.
And at the end @esp = 2283968 after de-serializing 6000 items. 
So total stack used was 1000 bytes only.
Seems like MFC serialization behavior is changed from vc9 to vc10/11 ,so stack is not getting reset to lower values in between recrsive calls.

1. Kindly let me know why this is happening ?
2. I aleardy have linked list data serialized for 6000 items. I want to deserialize these items.Can i retrive this recursivly stored data using any of non-recursive method (which will not require this recursive de-serialization call )?

Waiting for your reply.

Regards,
Amit

PS- Recently i have modified this class to store COBJLIst retrived from linked list items.

And while deserialization we retrive this list and construct linked list out of it.

So now onwards save and retrive will not have any issu.Problem is ,i am trying to retrive old version data where in we have dumped linked list data.

Comment: Compile with /Zi instead of /ZI to reduce stack usage.

Answer (score 0):

Your serializable class should have only what it should serialize, and hence `MyClass *m_pNext` is not a good candidate. Also, `Serialize` need **not** to do following:

```
ar.SerializeClass(RUNTIME_CLASS(MyClass)); 
UINT objSch = ar.GetObjectSchema();
CObject::Serialize(ar);
```

The method `SerializeClass` should be called for the base class, so that the base should be serialized also. In your case there is no user-defined base class that needs to be serialized. You are serializing the same class. Remove these three lines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actualy MyClass is some class which is derived from another class Y.And Y is derived from CObject. I forgot to remove these lines from original code. I can not share original code so modified it little bit.

Now this code was working fine for vc9 .vc10/11 its stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you currently detect that you have loaded all the list in deserialization. If you save `m_pNext` pointer value with other fields you can separate serialization of item fields and whole list to avoid recursion like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void Serialize(CArchive& ar)
    {
        if (ar.IsStoring())
        {
             for (MyClass* node = this; node != NULL; node = node->m_pNext)
             {
                  node->SerializeFields(ar);
             }                 
        }
        else
        {
            for (MyClass* node = this; node != NULL; node = node->m_pNext)
            {
                node->DeserializeFields(ar);
                if (node->m_pNext)
                {
                    // replace garbage with valid pointer if needed
                    node->m_pNext = new MyClass(); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
private:
    void SerializeFields(CArchive& ar) { /* store all variables */ }
    void DeserializeFields(CArchive& ar) { /* load all variables */ }
```

Comment: Hi, The recursive data is already stored by users.And i have to work on old version data which is stored in format specified in above code.For future versions i may implememt new thing but what about old version ? reading problem is coming with old version data.

Comment: It is not clear how do you currently determine when to stop deserialization. You can use same method with none-recursive approach. This code will deserialize old data if `m_pNext` field value is also saved to archive, so when deserializing NULL value read will indicate end of the list.

Comment: De-serialization stops automatically ( by MFC) when data is finished.But it is not going till end out of the list because of stack overflow.